# Finding Capital Char in String in DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have requirement of fetching capital chars from a given string using DWL.
Example - input string - KinLiCheng then output should be KLC.
Is there any DWL syntax which do this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can use several [DataWeave expressions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation) combination to manipulate the String:

1. **scan** to get an array with all Capitalized character: `"KinLiCheng" scan /[A-Z]/`
2. **flatten** to flatten the array result from step #1 into a single simple array: `flatten ( ... )`
3. **joinBy** to merge the array above into a single string value: `joinBy ""`

Complete expression: `flatten ("KinLiCheng" scan /[A-Z]/) joinBy ""`

Answer (score 0):

We can use **regex** for doing this

```
"KinLiCheng" replace /[a-z]/ with ""
```

Can be done Without regex also

```
("KinLiCheng" splitBy "") -- ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

though not a pretty solution

**splitBy** will convert the string **KinLiCheng** into an array

**Array representation** of string **[
  "K",
  "i",
  "n",
  "L",
  "i",
  "C",
  "h",
  "e",
  "n",
  "g"
]**

**--** is dataweave operator to remove elements from array

[Further reading on Dataweave operators](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators)